# How do you "unfeature" a sticker book page?

Tags: steam

I've managed to find all summer stickers in a single page, which has given me the option to feature that page on my profile. However, after doing so, I don't see a way to remove the stickers from my profile, either from my profile options or from the stickers page.
How can I remove the features sticker page from my profile?

Comment: There is no undo... only stickers

Comment: @n_palum If you know the answer, post it as such.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm not sure that *is* an answer, more an attempt at a witty comment, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the Summer Sale Stickers have been buggy. But [supposedly](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2592234299527728699/) you can go to your pages, remove all the stickers from the page, and hit save. This [should](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2592234299527410077/) automatically remove the showcase from your profile.

Comment: I think those are the right links (To what provided the answers), I can't open them from my location at the moment. But they should be. Searching "how to remove sticker pages from steam profile" warranted most of these results.

Comment: Should also be noted that at the time of writing this comment, the sticker book should still be accessible despite the sale ending by appending `/stickers` to your steam profile URL, where this can still be done to remove the sticker showcase.